# Is the sentence "Because something is ..., so is something" correct?

Tags: conjunctions

I have a sentence "*Because A and B are finite, C is finite*". Then I think of a way to remove the duplicate of "finite" with "*Because A and B are finite, so is C*".

Could you elaborate if this sentence is grammatically correct?

Comment: I personally think *Because my mother and father are English, **I am** [English] **too*** sounds "better" than ***...so am I***. But it's just a stylistic choice - as it would be if you went for the "default" structure whereby you make the assertion *first*, and *then* "explain" it: *C is finite **because A and B are** [finite]*. Or in my case, ***I'm English because my parents are.***

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical. Note that (a) _because_ is unnecessary to the structure or its meaning; other subordinating conjunctions will work (_While Mary is well-qualified, so is Jennifer_); (b) the sense of _cause_ here is logical, not physical: f(A) & f(B) implies that we must conclude f(C), but that fact is not responsible for the fact of f(C); it's merely evidence.